# Is it possible to observe postMessages using webdriver.js?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to make Selenium perform certain actions once an iframe on the webpage sends a particular postMessage to the parent window. In order to do that, I need either to get access to the `window` object of the web page that the browser is on from the test runner (so that I could observe postMessages on `window` directly in the test runner), or to somehow connect javascript that is executed in the browser to javascript that is executed in the node test runner (pass a callback from the test runner to the browser that will be called when the window receives the postMessage, or something). Is there any method for doing this? Google was no help with this one :-(

**UPDATE:** Hmm, executeAsyncScript looks very promising; I wonder whether I could it into listening to postmessages and then notifying the callback provided by the test runner that a particular postmessage was received.

Answer (score 1):

@azangru did you ever find a solution to this over the last two years?

I tried `executeAsyncScript` and it theoretically could work, except that it seems to block other actions from completing until it resolves.

Code mockup in TypeScript: https://gist.github.com/JoshuaKGoldberg/a0c5fe2812a06318e0eb2ffdc9e17021

Filed Selenium issue: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5972

In the meantime, you could have the page `console.info` stringified forms of the data it wants to transmit, then continuously poll for logs in Selenium. Not great but better than nothing...?

Comment: No, I am afraid I haven't. Didn't end up testing messages eventually. Seeing your comment now I thought: surely, Puppeteer would be able to do that, but I see that you already investigated that and found that it can't.

Comment: Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49808578/how-to-listen-to-postmessage-messages-in-puppeteer